# Problemas con API y sesión en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

Los pongo en contexto; creé una API y estoy consumiéndola, sin embargo, me encuentro con un problema que realmente no sé cómo solucionar.
A la hora de que un usuario haga login, estoy creando una sesión para guardar su identificador (id). Funciona correctamente en Postman y al parecer también en la página web, pues me devuelve lo mismo. A continuación lo que devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene a la hora de utilizar otro servicio (find). Obviamente, hay un middleware de por medio que me verifica si esa sesión está o no activa (para saber si el usuario está logueado o no). En Postman funciona correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, en la página web no funciona. El middleware interviene porque al parecer la sesión no está siendo creada.
Código API:

```
public function __invoke(object $dto)
{
    if(!password_verify(
        $dto->password(), 
        $this->verifyEmail($dto->email())['password'])
        )
    {
        throw new InvalidPasswordException('Contraseña incorrecta');
    }
    
    $_SESSION['uuid'] = $this->verifyEmail($dto->email())['uuid'];
}

private function verifyEmail($email)
{
    $verifyEmail = $this->repository->login($email);

    if(count($verifyEmail) == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidEmailException('Email incorrecto');
    }

    foreach($verifyEmail as $data)
    {
        $uuid = $data['uuid'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        break;
    }

    return [
        'uuid' => $uuid,
        'password' => $password
    ];       
}
```

Código Front (donde se consume esta API a través de GuzzleHttp)

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $response = $this->guzzle->request('POST', 'login', [
        'form_params' => [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]
    ]);
    return $response->getBody()->getContents();
    
}
```

¿Por qué al parecer no me crea la sesión? ¿Debo crear la sesión en el FRONT donde estoy consumiendo la API?

Documentación de la API con Postman:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/18194615/UVXnJEp4

Mil gracias

Comment: porque un `foreach($verifyEmail as $data)` si solo debes verificar un solo email...? no obstante a que ruta llamas y que parametros le pasas como lo haces? en postman solo se muestra el resultado con 4 campos!

Comment: Hola, qué tal. Gracias por responder. Debo cambiar la manera en la que realicé la consulta con Eloquent para quitar de por medio ese foreach. Colocaré la documentación de la API con Postman que realicé para que, si gustas, revises los parámetros. @Bryro

Comment: ¿Por qué haces dos llamadas a `verifyEmail()`, tanto aquí: `if(!password_verify(
        $dto->password(), 
        $this->verifyEmail($dto->email())['password'])
        )` como aquí: `$_SESSION['uuid'] = $this->verifyEmail($dto->email())['uuid'];` ¿?